# Slow / Lagging Radio button using jquery IE 10 versus Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

IE 10 / Chrome / jquery 1.10.2 / Standard template from Visual Studio 2013 (i.e. .Net 4.5)

I have 10 radio button or so, and when I click one of them, 2 things happen: 
1. I recreate all the radio button
2. I update some charts

In Chrome, when I click, things happen instantaneously. In IE 10, the button get filled with black for a few seconds before it get selected and things start moving.

```
 var input = $('<input type="radio" class="chartOptions" value="' + myList[i] + '"  name="' + mySelection[0] + '"/>').click(
                       function () {
                               changeSelectedProduct(this, myListCol, myParentCol, myLevel, mySelection);
                       });

 function changeSelectedProduct(esrcElement, myListCol, myParentCol, myLevel, mySelection) {
           addFields(esrcElement.parentNode, null, myListCol, myParentCol, 1, mySelection);
           drawCharts();
   }
```

I tried figuring out which row is delaying the whole thing. It seem proportional to the actual computation time of each. So none in particular. If I remove both addFields() and drawCharts() it goes flawlessly. If only one of the, it goes faster but not perfect.

What could cause this? 
**ANSWER:** The fact that Chrome updates the screen after addFields, before drawcharts. However, IE only update the screen after drawcharts.

Now how to force IE to update the screen?

Comment: Why not use the onchange event instead of onclick event?

Comment: Just tried: same results. Why would onchange be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       setTimeout((function () {
           addFields(.....);
       }), 0);
       setTimeout((function () { drawCharts(); }), 0);
```